# My /tp command doesn't work as intended in command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, the idea is that player should be teleported back in the hallway as they pass through a specific coordinates, and this part works just fine.

However, I also need them to be facing 90 degrees to the right after the teleportation (for example if player was looking -180, he will be rotated to -90). But my command doesn't work, and it just sets players view to 90 / 0 after teleportation. What should I do?

`/execute as @a[x=2538,y=-58,z=1133,distance=..1] as @s run tp @p 2531 -58 1126 ~90 ~`

Comment: Just curious, but what version is this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it to be 90 degrees relative to the direction you were looking, you might be able to store direction data as an armor stand or something, then run a command based off that. Ill look into it, but hopefully this is a start.

**Edit:** First summon the armor stand:

```
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:'[{"text":"RotStore"}]'}
```

This merges the rotation of the nearest Player to an armor stand:

```
/execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,sort=nearest,limit=1,name=RotStore] run data modify entity @s Rotation set from entity @p[distance=..32] Rotation
```

The issue however, is that player data cannot be modified in the same way, otherwise we could just do "modify entity player rotation set from armor stand". It is possible to set rotation to whatever you want via the tp command, but I unfortunately do not see it being possible to have this be dynamic.

If it is possible, It would likely require a ton of commands.